# linux-headers uname mismatch

Tags: upgrade, kernel

The headers I have in my `/usr/src` are `linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic` and `linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae`, but

```
uname -r
```

returns

```
3.0.0-12-generic-pae
```

`cat /proc/version agrees` with uname.

I downloaded the linux source.  I did not get any header files with it. '`find /`' does not find '`linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic-pae`' on the system.

When I try to build my video drivers it complains about the mismatch. What should I be using?

I got to this state by upgrading from 11.10.  Maybe the upgrade failed.

When I log in, I get the message

```
Welcome ... to 12.04.3 (GNU/Linux 3.0.0-12-generic-pae)
```

followed by

```
New release 12.10 available
```

yet

```
do-release-upgrade
```

returns

```
No new release found.
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of troubleshooting steps before I can provide a real answer.

1. Can you provide the contents of `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`? This will help diagnose the issue with the update-manage, but that's mostly tangential to your kernel problem since that updates via `apt`. Did you recently do a distribution upgrade?
2. Additionally a listing of `sudo dpkg -l`. You'll want to try to trim that down to packages that seem relevant. I don't have a shell handy or I'd `grep` it out for you. Try `headers` , `linux`, etc.
3. Additionally, have you rebooted since your last `apt-get upgrade`? If not, the upgrade may not have taken effect yet since the kernel <strike>needs</strike> may need to be brought down to update.

Older kernel versions can be removed from your system using your regular package management preferences (apt, synaptic, etc). This will ensure you are running the newest version.

Comment: 1) 'cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades' "Prompt=lts"

Comment: By default LTS versions (April of even number years) do not upgrade until the next LTS release (which will be 14.04). If you want 12.10 you must edit that file to say `prompt=normal`.

Comment: 1) 'cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades' "Prompt=lts"  2) 'sudo dpkg -l' yields "ii linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic-pae 3.0.0-12.20" "ii linux-images-3.2.0-57-generic-pae 3.2.0-57.87" "ii linux-image-generic-pae 3.2.0-57.68"  N.B. the current is 3.2.0-57.68 an older subrelease than the specific 3.2.0-57.87.  3)  Yes, I have booted several times.

Comment: Setting prompt to normal allowed the 'do-release-upgrade' to work.  The headers now match!  Thank you for your knowledge.